# How to make bootstrap 4 carousel work with grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I've successfully built a little drag and drop builder with [grapesjs](https://grapesjs.com/docs/#what-is-grapesjs). Works great. The problem I'm facing is when dragging a bootstrap carousel inside the builder. The carousel works as expected on a regular page. But when inside the framework, only the first image shows up and I'm unable to use the controls to switch from one image to another. I've looked into the [lory plugin](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-lory-slider) but I'd love to be able to do this with bootstrap. Any grapesjs expert who can help?

See my builder here on Codepen :
https://codepen.io/hellomev/pen/RwRaNpZ

**To reproduce :** Open Blocks. Then drag and drop one of the carousel inside the builder.

grapejs

```
function customPlugin(editor){
    //slide1
    editor.BlockManager.add('slide1', {
    category : 'Carousel',
    label: '<h1><i class="far fa-play-circle fa-lg"></i></h1> Slides only',
    content : '<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> <div class="carousel-inner"> <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(35).jpg"> </div> <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(33).jpg"> </div> <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).jpg"> </div> </div> </div>'
    });
    //slide2
    editor.BlockManager.add('slide2', {
    category : 'Carousel',
    label: '<h1><i class="far fa-play-circle fa-lg"></i></h1> Slides With controls',
    content : '<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> <div class="carousel-inner"> <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg" alt="First slide"> </div> <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(46).jpg" alt="Second slide"> </div> <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(47).jpg" alt="Third slide"> </div> </div> <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>'
    });
    
    }
    
    
     var editor = grapesjs.init({
    container : '#gjs_container',
    storageManager: {
    type: 'remote',
    autosave: true,// Store data automatically
    autoload: true,// Autoload stored data on init
    stepsBeforeSave: 1,
    urlStore: 'queries/save_webpage.php',
    urlLoad: 'queries/load_webpage.php',
    // For custom parameters/headers on requests
    params: { _some_token: '' },
    headers: { Authorization: 'Basic' },
    },
    plugins: [
    customPlugin
    ],
    pluginsOpts: {},
    canvas: {
    styles: [
    'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css',
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css',
    ],
    scripts: [
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js',
    ],
    }
    });
```